# Guess why fiddle work and on my website doesnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

This is the simple Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeIndex = $('#bmenul > li.totalactive').index();

    $('#bluenzbarimg').css({
        'marginLeft': (180 * activeIndex) + 'px'
    }).show();

    $('#bmenul > li').not('.totalactive').hover(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('#bluenzbarimg').stop().animate({
            'marginLeft': (180 * index) + 'px'
        }, 400);
    }, function() {
        $('#bluenzbarimg').stop().animate({
            'marginLeft': (180 * activeIndex) + 'px'
        }, 400);
    });
});​
```

This is [**the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rzJMv/10/) with almost exactly the same code than the website (except some css) and here [**the website**](http://www.bluenz.com/).

Comment: Developer console is your friend.

Comment: Your website shows this error: `TypeError: $(".bs-docs-sidenav").affix is not a function` which stops other javascript executing i'd guess.

Comment: Getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'affix'`, Check this...

Comment: -1 as this question does not show any research effort. Basic debugging would have shown the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'affix'` in `application.js at line 17` which is: `$('.bs-docs-sidenav').affix({`

Comment: wow you guys developer tools are rubbish. `[object Object]` what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing because

```
$('.bs-docs-sidenav').affix({
```

does not have the affix method, and therefor the rest of your javascript fails to load..

Either, you are missing a javascript include, or you just need to remove that call!

Comment: Chrome console shows: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'affix' - application.js:17

Comment: I Saw that error, but i have other javascript codes that work... The think is that when you say that, i looked for that files, include it (thinking that is stupid) and.... now is fixed... Thanks so much, my bad for not considering everything like a possible reason for this error.